# can't set a breakpoint in vsc while writing in C - module hasn't loaded

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, breakpoints

im trying to write a program in C, when I run it it says

```
a.out: malloc.c:2617: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
```

I don't understead what this means, but when I tried to debug I coudn't even place a breakpoint because apprantly "Module containing this breakpoint has not yet loaded or the breakpoint address could not be obtained."

I have no idea what to do with that, and would very much apreciate any help.

Comment: When you catch the assertion in your debugger, where in ***your*** code does it happen?

Comment: As a probable big hint: The place where this happens is unlikely where the actual error is. You likely wrote out of bounds of previously allocated memory somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understead what this means

It means that your code invokes [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) most likely dereferencing [wild or dangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) pointers or writing outside arrays (or allocated memory). This error shows that the memory allocation system has detected a problem.

> but when I tried to debug I coudn't even place a breakpoint

do not even try to debug standard library functions. They work well, but your code does not. The source of this problem is **your** program, not the standard library functions.

Unfortunately, you did not post your code, so I cant say what is wrong there.